# Request to reopen "Resistance decreases with temperature"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

["Resistance decreases with temperature". How to interpret this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/579393/resistance-decreases-with-temperature-how-to-interpret-this-sentence) doesn't seem like an unreasonable question to ask on ELU, but it's been summarily closed with the "justification"...

> *...because it belong [sic] to an SE site on physics or EE*

It might have been acceptable to migrate to ELL, but I personally wouldn't be inclined to do that with this exact question. Imho it's not *that* obvious that ***X increases / decreases with Y*** implies that both variables always change "in tandem". Noting [the closer humans get to them](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/303179/the-closer-humans-get-to-them) as recently asked on ELL, I suspect some people might assume that the construction involved here simply means ***If X changes then Y changes** (but not necessarily in the same "direction").*

Anyway, I won't keep on. If you agree with me that the question is acceptable (it's *What do these words mean?*, not *What are the laws of physics?*) then please vote accordingly - ***to reopen***, on the linked question on the Main site, not ***for*** this Meta question!

Comment: I think reopening was well justified. There is a tendency from some contributors to fail to see past the specialist content of a question to the English. In this case a fragment of physics was sufficient to prompt such closure. And so it is that we too often see questions like this closed whereas a similar question about "... expectations rise with affluence ... " would probably have been acceptable to these contributors.